# RC servo power switch not working properly

Tags: pcb, switches, schematics, servo, troubleshooting

I am troubleshooting an ESP32 PCB I designed. Every function is working properly except the RC servo (Futaba HPS-AA701) I am using is not switched off when its ground is opened by a switch.

My PCB is made of a motherboard (schematic attached) and a daughter board (schematic attached) through an 8 pin header connector (labelled H2 on the motherboard and H1 on the daughter board). An RC servo is connected on the connector labelled U6 on the motherboard.

The boards are powered on/off with the main power switch (SW2 on the daughter board). The RC servo is powered on/off with its own switch (SW3 on the daughter board). The main switch opens/closes GND of the whole board while the servo switch opens/closes only the GND of the servo.

The thing is, when SW2 is closed and SW3 opened, the servo is still powered. There is 3.2V between its terminals (VCC and servoGND). It is undervoltaged so it is acting randomly. I though that the servo would be powered off when servoGND is opened. However, some current seems flowing through VCC and PWM. I think I should have used VCC to switch off/on the servo but I would like to understand/modify the PCB I have.

[image: Daughterboard]
[image: Motherboard]

Comment: Why don't snip and insert the images into your question?

Comment: I'm not opening a random google drive file but ground switching, while popular for automotive applications, isn't recommended unless the device is designed for it.  You might be seeing current flowing through a data path or maybe your switch device doesn't maintain its state when the driving circuit is unpowered.  A quick search shows many people experience problems switching ground to servos.